# Control Scroll in Child Page From Parent Page Using JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can you please let me know if it is possible to control the scroll to element which is in child page from parent page?

Lets say I have  `a.html` like this

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="index.html">Homepage</a>
    <a href="2.html#app">App</a>
    <a href="2.html#map">Map</a>
    <a href="2.html#tap">Tap</a>
</div>
```

and in `2.html` I have

```
<body>
    <div id="app" style="height:600px;">App Section</a>
    <div id="map" style="height:600px;">Map Section</a>
    <div id="tap" style="height:600px;">Tap Section</a>
</body>
```

now what I would like to do is when a user clicks on each of links `App`, `Map`, or `Tap` first load the `2.html` and then scroll to the linked section?

Thanks

Comment: So like smooth scroll down the page after it is loaded instead of loading at the id?

Comment: but how to figure out which section has been requested to be scroll to?

Comment: Is it not scrolling at all?